# sort dataframe alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

```
birth_data.sort_values(by='name',ascending = True)
```

- name      numbers

  2. bruh     96570
  3. gib      95095
  4. mel      115195
  5. nish     112055
  6. raw      88018

I can sort the "numbers" but if i replace it with "name" I receive an error.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2441             try:
-> 2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: It means there are no column `name`, what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
birth_data.sort_values(by=['name'], ascending = True)
```

Edit: Are you sure there is a column called 'name'?

Comment: `by` parameter can be a string or list of strings.

Comment: You are right. I think that the problem is the dataframe don't have a "name" column.